# Google Sheet formula to SUM employees monthly cost

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have  to calculate monthly costs of people. Here is what I have and it gives 0 each time. Any idea please? I use google sheets with ";" as the separator in formulas. I need to calculate how much work force costs each month regarding join and exit dates if someone left. People cost should be sum of month costs and reduced (dayly prorata) if someone exited in middle of a month.

The formula I tried here gives nothing/blank. I can't figure out after few hours of trying. Any ideas?

```
=SOMME.SI.ENS(G3:G8; C3:C8; "Yes"; A3:A8; "<="&FIN.MOIS(J3;0); E3:E8; ">"&FIN.MOIS(J3;-1))
```

[image]

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B9aR2lmiluIKY2LTEJbBQuWqAqLWVl0D3wow5-fxn_Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see [ask]. All information needs to be in your question, not in comments, and your title needs to be a clear, specific question.

Comment: "reduced if someone exited in middle of.."<-- You need to specify how you calculate `monthly costs` when there is a partial month. Please state the explicit formula in your question. (ie. Do not require others to dig it in your sheet.) Right now, a formula cannot be inferred also because your sheet assumes 4 weeks per month -- while a month is partial by num of days. Obviously, a real-life month is rarely 4 weeks. So your sheet is not directly translatable from real life. Still, the point is, dont require answerers to infer your core requirements. State every one explicitly in your question.

Comment: yes sorry, i added dayly prorata

Comment: For month `October` your expected result shows 3000 for Employee3 (half month) ; so as per *pro-rata* should it be ***(6000/31)*15 = 2903*** ?!  similarly if exit date is Oct 5(in place of Oct 15) then it would be ***(6000/31)*5 = 968*** ?!

Answer (score 0):

This anwser looks good:

```
=BYROW($J$3:$J;LAMBDA(m;IF(m="";;SUM(FILTER(MAP($E$3:$E;$G$3:$G;LAMBDA(e;c;IF(c="";;c*IFS(OR(e="";e>EOMONTH(m;0));1;e<m;0;TRUE;CEILING((e-m)/(EOMONTH(m;0)-m+1);0,5)))));$A$3:$A<=EOMONTH(m;0)))))) in K3.
```